# How to pass a variable to Selection.Find

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write VBA code (MS Word) to look for paragraphs starting with a number and a period (like bullet points, but plain text)

1. First paragraph
2. Second Paragraph
3. Third Paragraph

So far I have

```
Do While Selection.Find.Found = True
fieldStart = "^p" & fieldCount & "."
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .Execute FindText:=fieldStart
End With
Loop
```

but it doesn't work....

Comment: The first line will always evaluate to false because you haven’t executed a Find at that point. You will do better to use Find with wildcards. See https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @TimothyRylatt I'v tried .Execute FindText:="^[0-9]{1,}\." but it gives me 
Run-time error '5625':
^[ is not a valid special character for the Find What box
my original idea was to search for ^p1.  using the fieldStart variable, but it doesn't work.
I've tried using a Loop Until false at the end instead of the While at the begining, but it comes back false becasue it can't find the value of fieldStart

Answer (score 0):

When using wildcards to find a paragraph mark you need to use the character code instead. So your find text would be `"^13[0-9]{1,}."

So your code would be:

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Do While Selection.Find.Execute(FindText:="^13[0-9]{1,}\.")
    'add code for action to take on match
Loop
```

However, in VBA it is not good practice to use `Selection`, although on rare occasions it is necessary.

In this instance your code could be rewritten to use a `Range` object. When used in this way `Find` redefines the range to the range of the found match:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content
    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Do While .Find.Execute(FindText:="^13[0-9]{1,}\.")
        'add code for action to take on match
        
        'collapse range to allow Find to continue
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @Timothy Rylatt. your suggestion works, but it counts the whole document, I need to search for the section that the paragraphs are in first, then execute the code, but adding this in front of your code
With ActiveDocument.Content
    With .Find
     .Execute FindText:="Title of the paragraph"
    End With
End With
doesn't work, any ideas? Many Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusR1 - Then just use the code for `Selection`, if that's how you want to use it.